# How to run Multiple Exchanges in Pika/RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I want to create multiple exchanges with different exchange names in Pika/RabbitMQ.  But the code I have seen all creates an exchange, and then using SelectConnection type, then calls connection.ioloop.start() which just continously runs.

If I want to create multiple exchanges in Python, do I have to run them in multiple processes or use python threading?

Comment: What kind of `Connection` type do you want to use? And are you talking about publishing to the exchange or consuming from it? Or both?

Comment: Not sure I understand the different connection adapters.  The most tutorials seem to be with the blocking connection.  I was going to try the Select Connection, but again I seem to only be able to initiate polling for one consumer at a time.  And I want to publish and consume from topic exchanges

Comment: Having exchanges in RabbitMQ is not related to the way you connect to the broker. Declaring an exchanges could be seen as similar to creating a table on MySQL, you can create as many as you want on the same connection.